# Precision is always zero tensorflow metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, evaluation

I am using tf metrics for calculation of precision and recall but always getting 0.0, but im getting good accuracy when i am calculating by myself, is it bug of tensorflow or i am doing anything wrong.

```
with tf.name_scope("pointwise_accuracy"):
    correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
    self.classification_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
    self.precision = tf.metrics.precision(self.input_y, self.logits, name="precison")[0]
```

Output
Precision - 0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`tf.metrics.precision`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision) is meant to be used in binary classification problems only, and its arguments must be all `0` or `1` since, as the docs say, they will be converted to `bool`. If you are indeed working in a binary classification problem but want to use the logits as parameter, you can look at [`tf.metrics.precision_at_thresholds`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision_at_thresholds), which allows you to specify the threshold at which a prediction will be considered true.

However, since your manual calculation uses `tf.argmax`, it looks more like a multiclass classification problem, in which case you don't usually talk about precision/recall, but just accuracy, so you can look at [`tf.metrics.accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy), and pass `tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1)` and `self.predictions` as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on a multiclass problem.